# Program not showing up in Open With List, but shows up in Choose another app

Tags: nsis

I'm trying to get my program to show up in the "Open with..." list, but for some reason I'm only able to see it if I go to "Open with" -> "Choose another app". I'm trying to associate a file extension with my program and allow the user to choose which version of the program they want to open a file with. So far my .nsi file handles the file associations like so:

```
WriteRegStr SHCTX "Software\Classes\.foo" "" "Foo File"
WriteRegStr SHCTX "Software\Classes\.foo\OpenWithProgIds" "FOO_2_0" ""
WriteRegStr SHCTX "Software\Classes\FOO_2_0\shell\open" "FriendlyAppName" "Foo 2.0"
WriteRegStr SHCTX "Software\Classes\FOO_2_0\shell\open\command" "" "${install_dir}"
```

I'm able to see the different versions that I have installed (2.0, 2.1 etc.) when I go to "Choose another app", but I'd like to have these options available to the user right from the "Open with" list. Am I missing something? I've tried using `WriteRegStr SHCTX "Software\Classes\.foo\OpenWithList" "FOO_2_0" ""` as well but that didn't do anything.

Comment: `OpenWithList` needs a .exe name from `HKCR\Applications`

Comment: Please tell us your Windows version.

Comment: @Anders I just tried adding my `Foo.exe` to `HKCR\Applications` but using `OpenWithList` still doesn't show my application in the "Open With" list, only the "Choose Another App" list. I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: OpenWithList actually wants a subkey.

Answer (score 1):

`WriteRegStr SHCTX "Software\Classes\.foo" "" "Foo File"` is wrong, the default value is supposed to point to your ProgId (`FOO_2_0`), it's **not** the type description. That is not the reason it does not show up in the menu though.

I believe Windows checks some things and will not display your application in the menu if:

- It is already the default command for that file extension and/or there are no other "open with" registrations by other applications.
- The command under `shell\open\command` is not valid. If there is no valid path/name it cannot extract the icon.

Some of this information is also cached in the undocumented `FileExts` Explorer key and might create some false positives during testing.

This seems to display the menu:

```
!define open_command "cmd.exe" ; A valid icon source but not really a open command
WriteRegStr SHCTX "Software\Classes\.foo" "" "Paint.Picture" ; Simulate registration taken over by another application
WriteRegStr SHCTX "Software\Classes\.foo\OpenWithProgIds" "FOO_2_0" ""
WriteRegStr SHCTX "Software\Classes\FOO_2_0\shell\open" "FriendlyAppName" "Foo 2.0"
WriteRegStr SHCTX "Software\Classes\FOO_2_0\shell\open\command" "" '${open_command}'
```

*[image: Open with menu]*

You really should change the name of `${install_dir}`, it should be something like `!define open_command '"$instdir\myapp.exe" "%1"'`

Comment: I was able to replicate your screenshot using `Paint.Picture` as the default and `cmd.exe` under `shell\open\command` but it isn't working when I use my `foo.exe` unfortunately. `foo.exe` is also a subkey within `Applications`, and I can't imagine that it is not a valid path considering the icon for `test.foo` is showing the correct icon and I'm able to open my program.

Comment: You need to use the full path to your .exe. cmd.exe alone works because it is in a system folder. You should make sure your normal open menu item (when .foo points to your ProgId) works correctly (opens your application) before you start playing with open with.

Comment: Before I tried changing the `shell\open\command` value to `foo.exe` it originally pointed to the path in my C:\ drive where `foo.exe` resides. I'm able to double click my `test.foo` and open my program, as well as select another version through the "Choose Another App".

Comment: What happens if you do `WriteRegStr SHCTX "Software\Classes\.txt\OpenWithProgIds" "FOO_2_0" ""` for example? This should make Windows ignore the (does it need a menu) check since .txt should already be taken.

Comment: My program shows up in the "Choose another app" menu, but does not show up in the "Open With" list.